# Confidence interval for the parameter of a geometric distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, geometric-distribution

I have a problem proving this:
Given $C(x)=[0, 3/x]$ for all $x\in\chi$, with $\chi=\Omega$ being the sample space and $P_q=Geom(q)$ being the geometric distribution.

I have to show that C(x) is a confidence Interval for q but I don't know how to get started.

I've been given the tip $P_q([0,3/q])=P_q(x\in[0,3/q])=P_q(\{1,2,\lfloor3/q\rfloor\})$ and then use the geometric series. It also says that the function wont be steady and that I should nest it between two steady ones.

Why am I supposed to do that? Any tips are very appreciated.

Comment: Apply the definition of a confidence interval.

Comment: Does that mean I have to verify the inequalities $P_q(0<q)\geqslant\alpha$ and $P_q(q<q/3)\geqslant\alpha$ for all $q\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Those statements make no sense because $q$ is a *parameter*. It is not a random variable and therefore you cannot talk about its probability.

Comment: Oops I see that as well now. I assume that the definition for this problem is $P_q(u(X)<q<v(X))=\alpha$ for all q. Then I get the inequalities: $P_q(u(X)<q)$ and $P_q(q<v(X))$ but what is X in this problem? Is it some arbitrary geometrically distributed random variable?

Comment: Yes. One has to understand the question a little differently than stated: $\Omega$ *must* be a set of real numbers, rather than a general sample space, for otherwise $3/x$ is not guaranteed to be a real number.  $X$ is a random variable with a geometric distribution of parameter $q$.  Applying $C$ to $X$ gives the interval $[0, 3/X]$.  If this is to be a confidence interval for $q$, then it better have a pretty large chance of including $q$--no matter what $q$ might be. This indicates you need to compute the chance that $0 \le q \le 3/X$ (in terms of $q$), and you're off and running.

Comment: I tried calculating this: $P_q(\{1,2,\lfloor3/q\rfloor\})$$=q\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor3/q\rfloor}(1-q)^{i-1}=(1-q)^{\lfloor3/q\rfloor}$ 
  Is this the probability you were looking for, regarding $0 \le q \le 3/X$?
Or is this probability given by $P_q(0 \le q)=\sum_{i=0}^{q}P(X=i)$ but this doesn't make any sense, q isn't even an integer.   
  Sorry that I'm a little hard to carry through this. Thanks a lot for staying with me :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I solved the problem using the geometric sum and the definition of the floor function to define two enveloping functions of the probability:
$q\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor3/q\rfloor}(1-q)^{i-1}=1-(1-‌​q)^{\lfloor3/q\rfloor}$
The level for the confidence interval is then 0.05, or $e^{-3}$